Global SaSS import / Use Vite 6 SaSS 1.83
So I recently updated my react project dependency and I'm having an issue with SaSS.
Before the update I was importing a SaSS file in Vite's config file like so:
css: {
preprocessorOptions: {
  scss: {
    additionalData: `@import 'src/mixins.scss';`,
  },
},

According to this article the @import statement have been deprecated in SaSS 1.83, therefore I changed it to: additionalData: @use "src/mixins.scss" as *;, instead.
This worked fine until I updated Vite to version 6.0.4.. When running the App I get an error saying that could not find the src/mixins.scss file.
    [plugin:vite:css] [sass] Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @use "src/mixins.scss" as *;
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  

    src/App.scss 1:1  root stylesheet

So to recap, when running the latest version of Sass with Vite 5.4.0 it works fine with the @use statement in Vite's config file, however in Vite 6.0.4 it does not work and I get the Can't find stylesheet to import. error mentioned above.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
